# ImageView not displaying in android xml (relative layout)

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

![I had coded it in linear layout (code given below) but want to know how to do the same using relative layout, or is that just a bad idea given the layout?

linear layout -

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

   <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ocean"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  />

<TextView
    android:text="You're invited!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:background="#009688"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Bonfire at the beach"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:background="#009688"/>
```

][1]When using relative layout my ImageView does not appear on the screen:

```
  <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ocean"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/ocean"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove `android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"` and only use `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: RrelativeLayout does not support layout_weight. Only LinearLayout does.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_height="0dp"` This is wrong in your `ImageView`

Change this to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Basically you set your height as 0. So nothing to show.

**Edit :**

Also you can remove this `android:layout_weight="1"`. No need for weight in `RelativeLayout`

Comment: RelativeLayouts do not support weight. You need to use a LinearLayout as a parent container if you want to use weights.

Comment: I think you thinking reverse. No need weight in Relative Layout i accept. Then remove the attribute. Why should we go to the LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Please use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

Change your ImageView's height like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ocean"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/ocean"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `layout_weight` in `LinearLayout`.
Try this.

```
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertizal">

 <ImageView
   android:src="@drawable/ocean"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:id="@+id/ocean"/>
```